# the kivy's Pong game tutorial won't work on raspbian jessie

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I have some problems when I try to learn python GUI with kivy.I try to follow the tutorial on the kivy's official site. when I run this code on computer this work well but when I use it with raspberry pi on raspbian os, kivy 1.8.0, it just show up the dark window. Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()

   #:kivy 1.8.

<PongGame>:    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

Comment: In the future, code blocks can be added by highlighting the code and pressing ctrl+k, or by indenting all code by 4 spaces.

Comment: i guess there is a problem with naming the kv file. How are you naming it. Have you tried Pong.kv and pong.kv? Alternatively use builder from kivy.lang and the function Builder.load_string().

Comment: @PalimPalim i don't think because of the way i name it, I've tested the code with .kv and .py file on my computer and it work really well then i send those file to the rasp but it's won't work as my intention and on my pc

Comment: @bendl thanks for helping

Comment: @PalimPalim Thank for paying attention on my question. But i realize that the python app can't load the kivy file itself so i have to put some method to to load the file by applying
 from kivy.lang import Builder 
Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')

Comment: no it can, if it is in the same folder and has a specific name. did adding the builder.load_file solve your problem?

Comment: If the kv file is not loaded on rasberry pi, you should see a warning in the logs about the kv file being not found.

Comment: @PalimPalim yes add the builder_load solve my problem. I used to put it in the same folder and the two file on that folder are the files that I used in my pc, and it wont work

Comment: @Tshirtman Yes just find that line immediately, why its just cant find the kv file itself